# Add where clause for joined table with JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I have an one to many association between vocab and vocabml,

what need to be done with simple query (join two tables and filter based on description conditions):

```
select  * from vocab v
left join vocabml vm on vm.vocabid = v.id and vm.locale in ('uk','en'....)
where v.description like '%syst%'
or vm.description like '%syst%'
```

My attempt with criteria API raises exception: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.vocabmls] of basic type`

My code:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Vocab> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Vocab.class);
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);

Root<Vocab> root = criteriaQuery.from(Vocab.class);
root.fetch("vocabmls", JoinType.LEFT);

List<Predicate> predicates = = new ArrayList<>();


Predicate predicate = builder.or(builder.like(root.get("description"), "%" + description + "%"),
                      builder.like(root.get("vocabmls").get("description"), "%" + description + "%"));
predicates.add(predicate)

if(locales != null){
    List<String> ids = locales.stream().map(Locale::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Join<Vocab, Vocabml> vocabmlJoin = root.join("vocabmls", JoinType.LEFT);
    vocabmlJoin.on(builder.and(vocabmlJoin.<Vocabml> get("localeId").in(ids)));
}

criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {})).orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("description")));
return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

Comment: Can you copy the full stack trace, to see what line throws the exception?

Comment: It doesn't like this line root.get("vocabmls").get("description")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it like this, need to add condition using join

```
Predicate predicateJoin = builder.equal(vocabmlJoin.get("description"), description);
predicates.add(predicateJoin);
```

It will simple add `where vm.description =`

Also I changed this one to be OR not AND

```
 criteriaQuery.where(builder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {})))
```